# In Identity Server 4, is it possible to make logging out of one application log that user out in all applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I currently have a .net core application that uses Identity Server 4 to authenticate users. We have two different applications; an MVC portion of our site that users can login to, and a SPA that users have to login to as well. Is it possible to make it so that anytime the user logs out of one of those areas, that it logs out of both?

Answer (score 1):

This is the main idea of `Single Sign-On`. Not only single login, but also single logout. Identity Server 4 fully support this, but you just need to configure both your clients (the MVC app and SPA) with their proper configurations. [This](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/signout.html) is the official documentation about signing out. It works.

**EDIT**

PS: Have in mind that Identity Server **does not invalidate** the `access token`, once you are logged out. In other words - if you, by any chance, still have the access token, you will be able to use it, as long as it is valid (its validity period has not expired). This is why usually the `access token` is set to have a shorter lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 front channel ways to acheive this and I'd recommend using both.

1) Front channel log out which uses an endpoint registered against each client. When you sign out of IDS4 (assuming it's implemented properly) it will make a request to the registered endpoint for each app that was signed into during the current session. http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html

2) The session monitoring spec which uses a bit of javascript and cross-domain iframe magic to notify the client app when the user's session changes on the IDP. Using this you can immediately respond to changes and do any cleanup you need to. http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

As mentioned in m3n7alsnak3's answer this will not invalidate any JWT access tokens (you can use the revocation endpoint to revoke refresh or reference tokens however). Therefore I'd recommend having the client applications to the best job they can of clearing up any state they can, i.e. clearing all cookies, session/local storage etc.